# How to execute Docker container as root

Tags: docker

when I connect to the graph-tool container in Docker, I can only enter it as user other than root. And if I use `docker exec -it --user root graph-tool bash`, it always show the following information:
`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/home/user\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown`

could anybody tell me how to address it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found that I followed the docker official instruction to run the graph-tool in jupyter notebook where there is a code `docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -it -u user -w /home/user tiagopeixoto/graph-tool bash`. So I just modify `-u user` to `-u root`. And it successfully corrects.